# How change the background of the editor to transparent but keep a background for neo-tree

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm a beginner on neo-vim and I'm trying to change the background color of the editor to transparent but keep a background on neotree. Here is a pic of my config
[image]

I have already try to edit my colorscheme config (https://github.com/ellisonleao/gruvbox.nvim) by adding `transparent_mode = true`, but it remove the background of neo-tree too.

Thank for your response.

Answer (score 0):

By default `https://github.com/xiyaowong/transparent.nvim` keeps `Neotree`'s colorscheme background while the text editor can be toggled between transparent and the colorscheme. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature on the part of `transparent.nvim`, but I like it.